# 3d animation / Camera transformation and modern devices

Tags: android, animation, camera, transformation

In my app I have 3d transformations by means `android.graphics.Camera`. It seemed to work fine until I tried Nexus.

I installed the app on Nexus 7 (4.2.1) and Galaxy Nexus (4.1.2), both of them don't perform Camera transformation at all. I have two different views with Camera and both show standart animation and doesn't apply Camera transformations.

Who can explain such a behaviour?

UPD:
camera code

```
transformation.clear();     
transformation.setTransformationType(Transformation.TYPE_MATRIX);   
mCamera.save();     
final Matrix matrix = transformation.getMatrix();         
mCamera.translate(x,y,z);  
mCamera.getMatrix(matrix);  
matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);        
matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);         
mCamera.restore();
```

UPD2:
the same with Galaxy S3 (4.2), but not with S2 (4.0.4)

Comment: where is your  transformations code ?

Comment: can somebody try it on any Nexus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add to the end of getChildStaticTransformation

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16 /*JellyBean*/) child.invalidate();
```

Comment: I tried to use http://code.google.com/p/android-3d-flip-view-transition/
Seems it is similar problem, on Nexus 7, but your solution is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided by Mikhail works for me at the end of `getChildStaticTransformation`.

The only problem is the `getChildStaticTransformation` method will be always called.

My solution is to put the code just after updated x,y,z value for each item.

```
// items is a ArrayList of ControlItem for example
// x,y,z are custom property of ControlItem class

items.get(0).x = 250;
items.get(0).y = 100;
items.get(0).z = 0;

for ( ControlItem item : items )
{
    // Item must be invalidate with JellyBean and superior
    if ( android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16 ) item.invalidate();
}

// getChildStaticTransformation() will be called after, transformation will be applied
```