# Cover flow view invalidation never ending cycle

Tags: android, camera, invalidation, hardware-acceleration, coverflow

I'm trying to implement cover flow using ([Neil Davies implementation](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html)).
In my application I have to use hardware acceleration, but when I set the hardware acceleration property to true this coverflow implementation is not working well (It renders the camera translations very unsmooth and stucks when scrolling).

I tried to disable hardware acceleration only on the view layer - this did not help me.

According to some solutions I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800401/3d-animation-camera-transformation-and-modern-devices) ,[or here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987554/gallery-with-center-image-zoomedin-in-android) (and some others), I have to call to `View.invalidate()` after applying  the camera translation. As you can see in the attached code snippet I've added this line, but after adding this `invalidate()` call this `transformImageBitmap()` function is being called in a never ending cycle. As I understand after the invalidation of the view the view is being "layouted" and the `transformImageBitmap()`called again. This never ending cycle of the  `transformImageBitmap()` function causes some preformace issues in my application.

Here is my transformImageBitmap() function:

```
private void transformImageBitmap(View child, Transformation t, int rotationAngle)
{            
    mCamera.save();
    final Matrix imageMatrix = t.getMatrix();
    final int imageHeight = child.getLayoutParams().height;
    final int imageWidth = child.getLayoutParams().width;

    mCamera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f);

    float zoomAmount = 0;
    zoomAmount = Math.abs((float) (rotationAngle));

    mCamera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, zoomAmount - 300.0f); 

    mCamera.getMatrix(imageMatrix);               
    imageMatrix.preTranslate(-(imageWidth/2), -(imageHeight/2)); 
    imageMatrix.postTranslate((imageWidth/2), (imageHeight/2));
    mCamera.restore();

    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "in transformImageBitmap");
    child.invalidate();
}
```

How can I make this work properly?

Answer (score 0):

I test a solution and succeed. That is disable hardward acceleration in your activity. I mean whole Activity because I also did it on View and the bug still not fixed.

All you should do is to add:

```
<activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
```

to you Activity manifest.

Comment: I have tried both the options, i.e. the hardwareAcceleration tag set to false and the child.invalidate() inside the transformImageBitmap() method, still i am seeing constant view invalidation. please help me explore other options.